# When do you use a minimum-phase filter over a linear-phase filter

Tags: finite-impulse-response, delay, linear-phase

Q1) I have understood that linear-phase filters have more delay time whereas minimum phase filters implement a lesser delay time but introduce phase distortion artifacts which linear-phase filters avoid. For which applications in real-time DSP is minimum phase more useful than linear phase.

Comment: perhaps when delay is more important that preserving the waveshape of a signal.

Comment: Also, a minimum phase filter can be inverted and still be stable.

Comment: @CMDoolittle So linear filters are unstable when inverted? Is there any document you have that could explain this concept?

Comment: A minimum phase filter has all its poles and zeros inside the unit circle. When you invert it, the poles and zeros switch places, but this means the poles are still inside the unit circle, and it is therefore stable.

Comment: @CMDoolittle, what about zeros *on* the unit circle?

Comment: @Jazzmaniac I just found someone has posted this. Maybe this will be of help :) http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2241/what-is-the-true-meaning-of-a-minimum-phase-system